# How to decode an (unknown) Unicode character to its assigned name (description) on the command line?

Tags: linux, bash, unicode

Given an unknown Unicode character, how can I tell the (ASCII) name of that character using Linux cmdline tools only ?

I'm looking for a more elegant way than fetching the Wikipedia page on the Unicode block, grepping the HTML oder wikitext source for the charcter code and finding the description next to it.

Comment: I used `apt-get install uniutils; uniname < characters.txt`. Thanks for the quick help.